# How to zero-pad numeric variables in zsh (and maybe also bash?)

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, seq, zero-pad

In zsh, when I have to create a bunch of files with zsh, I usually do something like:

```
for x in $(seq 1 1000); do .....; done
```

This works fine, it gives me files with names `foo-1.txt` .. `foo-1000.txt`.
However, these files do not sort nicely, so I would like to zero-pad the `$x` variable, thus producing names of `foo-0001.txt` .. `foo-1000.txt`.

How to do that in zsh? (and bonus question, how to do it in bash?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `-w` flag to `seq` (in any shell):

```
$ seq -w 1 10
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

Comment: seq -w 001 005    #  pads

Answer (score 37):

For reference sake, if you do not have control over the generation of the numeric values, you can do padding with:

```
% value=314
% echo ${(l:10::0:)value}
0000000314
% echo $value
314
```

Comment: Seeing that ${(l... is not very search-engine friendly, look this up under Parameter Expansion Flags in zshexpn(1). Also paired delimiters can be used to make the syntax a bit more intuitive: ${(l{10}{0})value}.

Comment: Strangely, zmv doesn’t understand that form, though parentheses work fine: ${(l(10)(0))value}.

Comment: echo ${(l:3::0:)$((++value))}

Comment: a strange caveat: if the value is longer than the given length the first digits are cut of, e.g. for l=3 and a value of 1234 the output is 234.

Answer (score 12):

You can use bash's [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
$ for n in file-{0001..1000}.txt; do echo $n; done
file-0001.txt
file-0002.txt
file-0003.txt
file-0004.txt
file-0005.txt
file-0006.txt
file-0007.txt
file-0008.txt
file-0009.txt
file-0010.txt
...
file-0998.txt
file-0999.txt
file-1000.txt
```

Works in zsh too.

Answer (score 9):

in Zsh:

```
% my_num=43
% echo ${(l(5)(0))my_num}
00043
```

Answer (score 3):

Works in bash (don't know for zsh):

```
echo foo{0000..1000}.txt
```

Comment: `echo foo{0000..1000}.txt` for zsh

Comment: Thanks, @olejorgenb, it is {a..z} and not {a-z} in bash as well. A-Z is used in file globbing like ls [0-1]000.txt for example. Over 10 years nobody complained!

Answer (score 1):

1. printf
   Using printf to pad with zeros works in any shell:

   ```
   $ printf 'foo%03d.txt\n' $(seq 4)
   foo001.txt
   foo002.txt
   foo003.txt
   foo004.txt

   $           printf  'foo%03d.txt\n' {1..4}       # works in bash, ksh, zsh.
   $ n=4;      printf  'foo%03d.txt\n' {1..$n}      # only ksh, zsh
   $ n=4; eval printf '"foo%03d.txt\n" {1..'"$n"'}' # workaround needed for bash
   ```
2. Use brace expansion (only bash and zsh keep the leading zeros ksh don't).

   ```
   $ printf '%s\n' foo{1..004}.txt
   foo001.txt
   foo002.txt
   foo003.txt
   foo004.txt
   ```